# Is there a reason this is not closed for medical advice?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, advice

[fishy odor after consuming fish](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/25871/7951) has the classic

> There's a condition I know of two siblings having it.
>
> **[...]**
>
> So I'd like to know:
>
> **What's the name of this condition?**

I flagged it for closure for medical advice, but didn't comment as someone else already has. I must admit I may have accidentally clicked the wrong close reason and it won't tell me what I clicked for some reason; but that is by the by really as I know the correct close reason is displayed when the community votes have reached the tipping point.

@CareyGregory, who is normally quick to close these questions, has commented but not closed this question for some unknown reason. I am confused. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

It *was* closed as medical advice. Then the OP edited it to simply ask if there was a name for it, so I reopened it.

Although I suppose one could argue that naming it is diagnosing it, I think in this case that would be a bit pedantic and just not worth the argument. And in the end I think it's a pretty harmless question.

PS- You did vote correctly. It was closed on 3 March at 0116Z by you, Bryan Krause, and me. I then reopened it on 4 March at 2027Z.